ANTLR4: Why is it checking for Full Context?
I need some assistance identifying why this is checking for Full Context in my ANTLR4 Language:
Lexer: Here & Parser: Here
Shortened Parser with only the semi-relevant pieces:
startPlainString: evaluationString EOF;

evaluationString:
    function explicitEvaluationString?
    | explicitEvaluationString
;

explicitEvaluationString:
    bracePattern explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat*
    | bracketPattern explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat*
    | PERCENT validSubstitution explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat*
    | beginGenericText explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat*
;

explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat:
    bracePattern
    | bracketPattern
    | PERCENT validSubstitution
    | genericText
;

bracePattern:
    OBRACE { ++inBraceDepth; } explicitEvaluationString*? CBRACE { --inBraceDepth; }
;

bracketPattern:
    OBRACK evaluationString CBRACK
;

funName:
    FUNCHAR {++inFunction;}
; // TODO: A Substitution can be inside of a funName to create a function name. The same goes for [] calls.

function: funName funArguments? CPAREN {--inFunction;} ;

funArguments: funArgument ({inBraceDepth == 0}? COMMAWS funArgument)*?;

funArgument: evaluationString;

validSubstitution:
    complexSubstitutionSymbol
    | substitutionSymbol
;

complexSubstitutionSymbol: (
        REG_STARTCARET {lookingForRegisterCaret = true;} explicitEvaluationString*? CCARET {lookingForRegisterCaret = false;
            }
        | REG_NUM
        | ITEXT_NUM
        | ITEXT_LAST
        | STEXT_NUM
        | VWX
    )
;

substitutionSymbol: (
        SPACE
        | BLANKLINE
        | TAB
        | COLON
        | DBREF
        | ENACTOR_NAME
        | CAP_ENACTOR_NAME
        | ACCENT_NAME
        | MONIKER_NAME
        | PERCENT
        | SUB_PRONOUN
        | OBJ_PRONOUN
        | POS_PRONOUN
        | ABS_POS_PRONOUN
        | ARG_NUM
        | CALLED_DBREF
        | EXECUTOR_DBREF
        | LOCATION_DBREF
        | LASTCOMMAND_BEFORE_EVAL
        | LASTCOMMAND_AFTER_EVAL
        | INVOCATION_DEPTH
        | EQUALS
        | CURRENT_ARG_COUNT
        | OTHER_SUB
    )
;

genericText: beginGenericText | FUNCHAR;

beginGenericText:
    escapedText
    | ansi
    | { inFunction == 0 }? CPAREN
    | { !inCommandMatch }? RSPACE
    | { !inCommandList || inBraceDepth > 0 }? SEMICOLON
    | { (!lookingForCommandArgCommas && inFunction == 0) || inBraceDepth > 0 }? COMMAWS
    | { !lookingForCommandArgEquals }? EQUALS
    | { !lookingForRegisterCaret }? CCARET
    | (OTHER|ANY_AT_ALL) 
;

escapedText: ESCAPE ANY;

ansi: OANSI ANSICHARACTER? CANSI;

And the full Lexer:
fragment WS: [ \r\n\f\t]*;

ESCAPE: '\\' -> pushMode(ESCAPING);
OBRACK: '[';
CBRACK: ']';
OBRACE: '{' WS;
CBRACE: '}';
CPAREN: ')';
CCARET: '>';
COMMAWS: ',' WS;
EQUALS: '=' WS;
PERCENT: '%' -> pushMode(SUBSTITUTION);
SEMICOLON: WS ';' WS;
OANSI: '\u001B' -> pushMode(ANSI);
RSPACE: ' ';
FUNCHAR:
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+ '(' WS
; // Lazy way of indicating printable characters. There's more printable characters than this!
OTHER: ~('\\' | '[' | ']' | '{' | '}' | '(' | ')' | '<' | '>' | ',' | '%' | '$' | ';' | ':' | '\u001B' | ' ' | '=')+;
ANY_AT_ALL: .+?;

// --------------- SUBSTITUTION MODE -------------
mode SUBSTITUTION;
COLON: ':' -> popMode;
REG_STARTCARET: [qQ]'<' -> popMode;
REG_NUM: [qQ][0-9] -> popMode;
VWX: [vwxVWX][a-zA-Z] -> popMode;
ARG_NUM: [0-9] -> popMode;
SPACE: [bB] -> popMode;
BLANKLINE: [rR] -> popMode;
TAB: [tT] -> popMode;
DBREF: '#' -> popMode;
ENACTOR_NAME: 'n' -> popMode;
CAP_ENACTOR_NAME: 'N' -> popMode;
ACCENT_NAME: '~' -> popMode;
MONIKER_NAME: [kK] -> popMode;
SUB_PRONOUN: [sS] -> popMode;
OBJ_PRONOUN: [oO] -> popMode;
POS_PRONOUN: [pP] -> popMode;
ABS_POS_PRONOUN: [aA] -> popMode;
CALLED_DBREF: '@' -> popMode;
EXECUTOR_DBREF: '!' -> popMode;
LOCATION_DBREF: [lL] -> popMode;
LASTCOMMAND_BEFORE_EVAL: [cC] -> popMode;
LASTCOMMAND_AFTER_EVAL: [uU] -> popMode;
INVOCATION_DEPTH: '?' -> popMode;
CURRENT_ARG_COUNT: '+' -> popMode;
ITEXT_NUM: [iI][0-9]+ -> popMode;
ITEXT_LAST: [iI] 'L' -> popMode;
STEXT_NUM: '$' [0-9]+ -> popMode;
OTHER_SUB: . -> popMode;

// --------------- ESCAPING MODE -----------------
mode ESCAPING;
ANY: . -> popMode;

// --------------- ANSI MODE ---------------------
mode ANSI;
CANSI: 'm' -> popMode;
ANSICHARACTER: ~'m'+;

The Actual Problem:
enter   startPlainString, LT(1)=abc
enter   evaluationString, LT(1)=abc
enter   explicitEvaluationString, LT(1)=abc
enter   beginGenericText, LT(1)=abc
consume [@0,0:2='abc',<15>,1:0] rule beginGenericText
exit    beginGenericText, LT(1)=
line 1:7 reportAttemptingFullContext d=11 (explicitEvaluationString), input=' %i0'
line 1:3 reportContextSensitivity d=11 (explicitEvaluationString), input=' '
enter   explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat, LT(1)=
enter   genericText, LT(1)=
enter   beginGenericText, LT(1)=
consume [@1,3:3=' ',<13>,1:3] rule beginGenericText
exit    beginGenericText, LT(1)=%
exit    genericText, LT(1)=%
exit    explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat, LT(1)=%
enter   explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat, LT(1)=%
consume [@2,4:4='%',<10>,1:4] rule explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat
enter   validSubstitution, LT(1)=i0
enter   complexSubstitutionSymbol, LT(1)=i0
consume [@3,5:6='i0',<41>,1:5] rule complexSubstitutionSymbol
exit    complexSubstitutionSymbol, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    validSubstitution, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    explicitEvaluationString, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    evaluationString, LT(1)=<EOF>
consume [@4,7:6='<EOF>',<-1>,1:7] rule startPlainString
exit    startPlainString, LT(1)=<EOF>

Where the issue is clearly demonstrated with the two lines:
line 1:7 reportAttemptingFullContext d=11 (explicitEvaluationString), input=' %i0'
line 1:3 reportContextSensitivity d=11 (explicitEvaluationString), input=' '

I'm trying to figure out why it's having trouble with Spaces.
It's identifying them as an RSPACE through the Lexer, I've confirmed this. So it's not triggering or otherwise considering the 'ANY_AT_ALL' alternative.
So why is it looking to do a full context expansion? I feel like I am missing something all too obvious.

This cannot be done without input! What is the input?

The input is abc %i0 and the start rule is startPlainString. Strictly speaking, there is no ambiguity here. But that is a fullback to SLL ("Strong LL") for "Decision 11". Generate the .dot for your parser grammar and find "d=11", you get it's in rule explicitEvaluationString. It's considered "normal" behavior in the parser (read https://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf, in particular the example on p5). If it becomes a drag on performance, you can try setting SLL mode for the parser. Or you can duplication the production and all refed productions and replace.

Also, you should stop downloading Java and building the tool jar, and storing it in git no less. Use "antlr4" from https://github.com/antlr/antlr4-tools. Call from command line antlr4 -v 4.13.1 -Dlanguage=CSharp -no-listener -visitor whatever.g4. Use the same Antlr4 tool version as the runtime. For CSharp, there is no 4.13.2. You should have tool and runtime versions identical.

The problem is that there has to be an RSPACE following firstCommandMatch ==> ... explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat. But RSPACE can optionally follow explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat because of the kleene *-operator on explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat. It now needs to make sure stop parsing  explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat for the last in a series of RSPACE. If you comment out all *command*, the choice at decision state 11 is deterministic, i.e., stack is not required, and there is no fallback.

Agreed with you on doing the tooling better. I intend to use the NuGet package for ANTLR4 tooling in the future. Storing binaries is not my idea of a clean github repository either.

I can certainly activate SSL. But I am curious about your last comment.
Are you saying that even though firstCommandMatch is not on the path for startPlainString, it still considers firstCommandMatch? Or are you calling it out for the other parsing-starts?
If so, is there a way to help optimize this? Or is it much as the same, and SSL will generally resolve this either way?

I just realized that it's Context Sensitivity, not Ambiguity. I've been staring at this for too many hours it'd seem.

Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. For a demo of why this is important, see https://github.com/kaby76/79161038. There you will find a parser driver with the original grammar, the other without certain rules, which does not have SLL fallback. Yes, it is possible to fix this using rule duplication so that it doesn't interfere with startPlainString. But it won't fix that for command. You can't have explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat end with RSPACE and expect to have firstCommandMatch followed by RSPACE. It's what I call an Antlr antipattern.

Would this thus be solved if there was a variety of explicitEvaluationStringConcatenatedRepeat -- say explicitEvaluationStringEnd that explicitly does not accept an RSPACE as a part of its genericText? What with  at the end of a string often needing to be trimmed anyhow.

I have a similar problem with EQUALS, SEMICOLON, and COMMAWS I imagine.

Hard to say. Already, the grammar is difficult to follow. I would try to simplify. Six entry points (i.e., EOF-terminated rules) seem unnatural. I would move semantic predicates and actions into a semantic analysis phase unless it corrected ambiguity.

Otherwise, replace RSPACE+ in command with  a predicate.

It does correct ambiguity. But can you tell me more about a semantic analysis phase? I think this is the first time I've heard that term.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Front_end

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
